# My easy button gives the wrong amount of colors

Tags: javascript, html

When I click mt 'Easy' btn that supposed to give me an output of 3 colors, it give me six like my 'hard' btn (also in the console I get 6 colors.

Part of my JS:

```js
var modeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".mode");
for (var i = 0; i < modeBtn.length; i++) {
  modeBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    modeBtn[0].classList.remove("selected");
    modeBtn[1].classList.remove("selected");
    this.classList.add("selected");

    //The short way - This called "the ternary oprator"
    /*
        this.textContent === "Easy" ? numSquares = 3: numSquares = 6;
        */
    //The longer  Way
    if (this.textContent === "easy") {
      numSquares = 3;
    } else {
      numSquares = 6;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="stripe">
  <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
  <span id="message"></span>
  <button class="mode">Easy</button>
  <button class="mode selected">Hard</button>
</div>
```

Here is my complete code at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/zaxWpv?editors=1111)

Comment: Change from `textContext` to `textContent`.  **Tip:** Use data-attr instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, I struggled with this one for about an hour...

Comment: Mmh, on easy I'm getting 3 colors.

Comment: numSquare = (this.textContent === "Easy") ? 3 : 6; is a little bit shorter

Comment: Maybe You could help me with a little thing related to this code... Somehow not all the squares responding to the mouse click. At the beginning I thought it was related to some latency but than I tried also on mobile an it's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged the code and found that the issue lies in the value of *i* in the method *init()*.

Once the document is loaded, the *init()* method adds event listener to both the buttons, *Easy* & *Hard*. When the value of *i* becomes 2, the loop terminates.

When the button is clicked, and since *i* is declared as *var*, which creates a scope at the function level and not the block level, *this.textContent* actually tries to access the value of **modeBtn[2]** which is **undefined**.

So, **the solution is to declare the variable *i* as *let***. This will definitely solve your problem.

Refer this [link](https://medium.com/coderbyte/a-tricky-javascript-interview-question-asked-by-google-and-amazon-48d212890703) for more details.